# How to debug dynamically generated method?

Tags: .net, debugging, dynamic, visual-studio-2012, il

I have a dynamically created assembly, a module, a class and a dynamically generated method.

```
AssemblyBuilder assembly = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(...);
ModuleBuilder module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule(...);
TypeBuilder tb = module.DefineType(...);
MethodBuilder mb = tb.DefineMethod(...);
ILGenerator gen = mb.GetILGenerator();
```

How can I debug method code generated with `ILGenerator`? I use Visual Studio 2012 debugger, but it just steps through a method call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to mark the generated code as debuggable.
Something like:

```
Type daType = typeof(DebuggableAttribute);
ConstructorInfo ctorInfo = daType.GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes) });
CustomAttributeBuilder caBuilder = new CustomAttributeBuilder(ctorInfo, new object[] { 
  DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | 
  DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default
});
assembly.SetCustomAttribute(caBuilder);
```

You also should add a sourcefile:

```
ISymbolDocumentWriter doc = module.DefineDocument(@"SourceCode.txt", Guid.Empty, Guid.Empty, Guid.Empty);
```

You should now be able to step into the dynamically generated method.

Comment: I caught an exception InvalidOperationException:Not a debug ModuleBuilder while executing `ISymbolDocumentWriter doc = module.DefineDocument(@"SourceCode.txt", Guid.Empty, Guid.Empty, Guid.Empty);`.

Comment: When you define the module you need to tell it to emit the symbol information. Use [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/76xbchca.aspx) constructor and set the second argument to `true`. There's actually a good working example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/02/03/366429.aspx).

Comment: A link that works today is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jmstall/debugging-dynamically-generated-code-reflection-emit

Comment: However, in the original article via archive.org you can see some highlighting that has been lost at learn.microsoft.com: https://web.archive.org/web/20101124032315/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2005/02/03/366429.aspx

Answer (score 2):

If you are generating raw IL without any source, then : this is always going to be rough. You might want to consider a package like [Sigil](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Sigil/), which is a wrapper around `ILGenerator`, but which will give you **useful error messages** (while emitting, not while running) if you make any subtle errors - stack corruption, etc.

Either that, or: write the module with save-to-disk enabled, and during debugging write a regular dll to disk - you can then run `PEVerify` on the dll, which will find most typical errors (again, stack corruption, etc). Or of course - you can load it into your favorite IL tool.